# Modify xml, child nodes with same name

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am trying to modify a xmlString so i can create a dataset on the fly.

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ttActivity>
    <a-actno>1030371</a-actno>
    <a-status>Start</a-status>
    <a-solution/>
    <a-descript>hei</a-descript>
    <a-descript>hopp</a-descript>  
    <a-acttypegr>0</a-acttypegr>
    <a-calltype/>
  </ttActivity>
</ds>
```

The problem when creating a dataset using dataset.ReadXML(xmlReader) is the 2 nodes with same name "a-descript". Is there a quick way to fix this xml so that the nodes get unique names. ie: a-descript1 and a-descript2 ??

Answer (score 0):

using LINQ to XML

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
doc.Descendants("a-descript").Last().Name = "a-descript2";
xmlString = doc.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi. We are getting somewhere but not quite there. I have many tables in the same xml and many of those tables have nodes with same name. (string arrays from db). Some tables can have string arrays up to 20 in length which gives a xml that have up to 20 nodes with same name. Can i use LINQ to fix all nodes with same name ?

Comment: I think i got it:  XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(outputXML);
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("so-info"))
                    {
                        element.Name = element.Name + i.ToString();
                        i++;
                    }